# Question about PostgreSQL performance tables

Tags: database, laravel, postgresql

I am working on redesigning a service to optimize it and I don't know which option to choose for a table.
I have two tables with many entries.

Table 1: `logs` (10M rows)
Table 2: `user_agents` (2M rows)

```
logs
+----+-----+---------------+-----+
| id | ... | user_agent_id | ... |
+----+-----+---------------+-----+

user_agents
+----+------+
| id | name |
+----+------+
```

Currently my table `logs` have a `user_agent_id` to go directly to the `user_agent` associated with the logs of a user's visit.
When a new visitor sends logs before saving them in the database I check that this user agent is already in the `user_agent` table otherwise I add it.

As long as the `logs` are not registered in the database, the user does not have access to the page he wants.

**I would like to optimize the writing speed in the logs table** and I would like to know if the fact of having separated its data into 2 tables is really significant in terms of writing time.
The alternative would be to put a `user_agent` column back into the logs table.

**Fontion to get id/insert user_agent** :

```
public function get_ua_id($headers)
{
    return ListUA::firstOrCreate(['name' => isset($headers['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) ? utf8_encode($headers['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) : '']);
}
```

Comment: 10M is not that much ... How much time your writings? Are they just inserts or updates? Is it really the time of writings that is low or is it the fact that you check the user_agent table before writing in the log table ?

Comment: I just insert all time. And it's about check the user_agent table before writing in the log table. Thank you

Comment: Simple question : is your column [user_agent].[user_agent_id] indexed ? If it is : are your statistics updated?

Comment: @Jaisus I think you mean [logs].[user_agent_id], yes I puted an index on it ! What do you mean by statistics updated ?

Comment: If you are looking in your [user_agent] table if it exists, you definitely need an index on the [user_agent] table. If the [user_agent].[user_agent_id] is declared as a primary key : it's already done. Do ANALYZE on your [user_agent] table to update the statistics. Just check the statistics update date also. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-analyze.html

Comment: I think your setup is reasonable. If there is a pain point, investigate that.

Comment: @Jaisus I'm not sure I understand, I updated the question with the tables. logs.user_agent_id is indexed and user_agents.id is primary. I will do an analyze to check that.

Comment: How do you check the presence of your user_agent_id in your user_agent table? by a previous request from your middleware? Maybe a trigger on the logs table could do the trick.

Comment: @Jaisus I just added the fonction I use to check the presence of the user_agent.

Comment: Yeah but what is using your function? The dataserver or another one? Are you going all the way from a server to another one twice? Maybe in this case the solution is to make that the verification is made on the data server side.

Comment: My server is under Plesk Debian 8. Everything is on the same server database and the app. The function is called when someone visit a specific URL of the app.